# Digest Authentication using Request PHP or any other in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, digest

I have used 
http://requests.ryanmccue.info/ and [https://github.com/rmccue/Requests](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/)

I am using Request library, but any other library can also be suggested.

My code for CodeIgniter

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
            public function index(){
                $this->load->library('PHPRequest');     
                $this->rest_client();
            }
            function rest_client(){
                $user = 'myusername';
                $pass = 'mypass';
                $BaseApiUrl  = 'myurl';

                $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
                $options = array('auth' => new Requests_Auth_Basic(array($user, $pass)));
                $request = Requests::get($BaseApiUrl, $headers, $options);
                var_dump($request->status_code);
                var_dump($request->body);

            }
        }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
int(401) string(28) "HTTP Digest: Access denied. "
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Curl PHP Now**

```
$options = array(
                CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
                CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // for https
                CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $username . ":" . $password,
                CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_DIGEST

        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        try {
          $raw_response  = curl_exec( $ch );
          // validate CURL status
          if(curl_errno($ch))
              throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), 500);
          // validate HTTP status code (user/password credential issues)
          $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
          if ($status_code != 200)
              throw new Exception("Response with Status Code [" . $status_code . "].", 500);
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception($ex);
        }
        if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($raw_response);
```